# Should updating props re-render the entire component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Let's say I have a `CookingClass` component that gets initialized like this.

```
let teachers = makeTeachers(["Amber", "Jason", "Lily"])
let students = makeStudents(["Hopper"])

<CookingClass
  teachers={teachers}
  students={students}
/>
```

One of the teachers dropped out:

```
let newTeachers = makeTeachers(["Amber", "Jason"])

<CookingClass
  teachers={newTeachers}
/>
```

It will make the entire component re-render. I am not sure whether React only calculates the diff and efficiently re-renders it or I must use `shouldComponentUpdate` to take care of it myself.

More real-world example might be implementing a Google map where there are a million markers and you want to replace one of the markers.

Comment: Yes, you should use `shouldComponentUpdate` to minimize re-rendering, and use `key`s to assure recycling.

Comment: Look into using react-redux. It solves this problem for you http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing a so called Virtual DOM node. For every change in a virtual node `shouldComponentUpdate()` gets called. If you don't implement it yourself it will always `return true;`

So if you only want to reload your `CookingClass` in specific cases you would have to implement it yourself.

The pro of React is that it will only re-render Native DOM nodes when they will get changed in the Virtual DOM. This is the "render" which makes React so fast.

Comment: Worth noting that when using the official `react-redux` bindings, `shouldComponentUpdate` is implemented and does not *always* return true.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample code, the component will re-render everytime.

You should use the [**react-redux**](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) ([documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)) bindings to "connect" the component to the store.

```
// ConnectedCookingClass.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import CookingClass from './CookingClass';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    teachers: state.teachers,
    students: state.students
  };
};

const ConnectedCookingClass = connect(mapStateToProps)(CookingClass);

export default ConnectedCookingClass;
```

Then use this component elsewhere like so:

```
// OtherComponent.js
import ConnectedCookingClass from './ConnectedCookingClass';

const OtherComponent = React.createElement({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ConnectedCookingClass />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

---

The react-redux bindings will do some smart things for you, like only re-rendering the component when the props returned by `mapStateToProps` are actually different than their previous value ([via a shallowEqual comparison](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/253ce8b3068d9d9bfe55f70a6f18a5fde313b326/src/components/connect.js#L163-L167)), so you should try to only return values here, no functions. Functions should be returned in `mapDispatchToProps`.

The default implementation of `shouldComponentUpdate` in react-redux will return true when:

1. ALWAYS if the component is a "pure" component (aka [stateless-function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions))
2. When the props have been updated manually (after componentWillReceiveProps called)
3. When the store has changed and the new props are different than the old props.

Here's what that looks like from the [source code](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/253ce8b3068d9d9bfe55f70a6f18a5fde313b326/src/components/connect.js#L76-L78):

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
  return !pure || this.haveOwnPropsChanged || this.hasStoreStateChanged
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **real** DOM Rendering is completely handled by React with very efficient `innerHTML` inserts and only for changes in the new data structure of your application VirtualDomTree.

`shouldComponentUpdate()` controls if the component should be **recalculated** or not. You should use it, when you are rendering statical data, for example. The output of the component will not change, so you could just return `false` and the first version of the component will be used for ever ;)